# MVC4 Source and VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

Background:

According to the documentation at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/documentation (under 'Getting and Building the Code' the very first item says:

```
The easiest way to work with our source is to install Visual Studio 2010 (with SP1).
```

I am running VS2010 SP1 and have managed to follow all of the instructions to get this source code up and running (on my Win7 64 bit machine). I am have the .NET 4.5 framework installed.

Problem:

During the build (from the command line) as well as from Visual Studio itself, I get the following error:

```
"The project file 'MY_LOCAL_PATH\src\System.Net.Http.Formatting.NetCore\System.Net.Http.Formatting.NetCore.csproj' cannot be opened. The project type is not supported."
```

Does anyone know how to get this project to load? All of the others in the Runtime.sln load fine.

UPDATE:

The two project type guids that are in the project file (csproj) are `BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3` and `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC`. The first has something to with Metro and the other is C#. I could understand the metro hangup but again the documentation says VS2010 SP1 is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/394550), the solution now requires VS2012 and Windows 8. I'll update the documentation Wiki accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I built each project separately and they all seemed to build with no problem. It appears that the other projects don't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

I have emailed a few people as well as this post to no avail. Looking more into this and my best guess is that because of the Metro project type I am going to need to get Windows 8 to get this to work. The MVC project does build regardless of this project so I am going to say this is the answer.